# Proving that if $\mathrm{NTime}(n^{100}) \subseteq \mathrm{DTime}(n^{1000})$ then $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes, p-vs-np

I'd really like your help with proving the following.

If $\mathrm{NTime}(n^{100}) \subseteq \mathrm{DTime}(n^{1000})$ then $\mathrm{P}=\mathrm{NP}$.

Here, $\mathrm{NTime}(n^{100})$ is the class of all languages which can be decided by nondeterministic Turing machine in polynomial time of $O(n^{100})$ and $\mathrm{DTime}(n^{1000})$  is the class of all languages which can be decided by a deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time of $O(n^{1000})$.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Hint: [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument).

Comment: where does this question originate from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution using padding. Suppose $L \in \mathrm{NTime}(n^{1000})$. Define a new language $L' = \{x0^{|x|^{10}-|x|} : x \in L\}$. Each $x \in L$ corresponds to some $y \in L'$ of length $|y| = |x| + (|x|^{10}-|x|) = |x|^{10}$. Therefore we can decide whether $y \in L'$ in non-deterministic time $|x|^{1000} = |y|^{100}$, i.e. $L' \in \mathrm{NTime}(n^{100}) \subseteq \mathrm{DTime}(n^{1000})$. In order to decide whether $x \in L$, form $y = x0^{x^{10}-|x|}$ and run the $|y|^{1000} = |x|^{10000}$-time deterministic algorithm for $L'$. We conclude that $L \in \mathrm{DTime}(n^{10000})$.

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem into two parts:

1. There is a $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language in $\mathsf{NTime}(n^{1000})$.
2. If an $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language is in $\mathsf{DTime}(n^{1000}) \subset \mathsf{P}$ then $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

Answer (score -2):

This is a near trivial consequence of the definition of NP-completeness. If any language in NP is solvable in polynomial time (which is asserted by the premise), then they all are. Another way to look at this is to look at [Cook's theorem for NP-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem) that reduces all NP-complete languages to the recognition of a language involving SAT and the conversion of the nondeterministic Turing machine into SAT.

Comment: What you said is true, but of NP complete languages (not NP languages).  We also need to show that there exists an NP complete language solvable in $NTime(n^{100})$-true, I think, but not obvious by definition.

Comment: agreed, good pt. think this follows from bounds in the Cook proof....? all NP machines can be converted/solved by SAT in NTime($n^c)$, $c<100$...?

Comment: @vzn: I don't think we can prove $c \lt 100$. I believe you might be contradicting one of the hierarchy theorems...

Comment: after thinking about it a little more carefully, agree. (initial glance, thought this was a basic question...) cooks proof creates a new SAT that is polynomially bounded in size relative to the original machine but the initial machine is unbounded in the polynomial exponent (wrt that proof). if I derived a contradiction then $P \neq NP$ =) ... anyway maybe we are saying this is actually an open question? ie not known to be either true or false wrt existing theory?

Comment: @vzn: The question can be solved using the technique of padding, alluded to by sdcvvc.