# relation between ntime and dtime

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time, nondeterminism

Given **DTIME**($n^2$) contains **NTIME**($n^{100}$) show that P=NP.

I think it's supposed to be straightforward but I just can't see it.

Take $L$, a language in NP. $L$ has a Turing machine which runs in **NTIME**$(f(n))$. If $f(n)$ is $\Omega(n^{100})$ it's obvious, but what about $O(n^{100})$?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Do you have things backwards in the last sentence?  The case where $f(n) = O(n^{100})$ seems like the easy one.

Comment: [Very closely related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/proving-that-if-mathrmntimen100-subseteq-mathrmdtimen1000-the?rq=1); duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* What is the time complexity of the fastest nondeterministic Turing machine that is a decider for $SAT$?

Comment: And it can be proved by padding even without a complete language involved.

Comment: It can also be proved by first showing 0=1.